# strange behaviour of list() in sikuli

Tags: find, behavior, sikuli

```
findAll(Pattern("excel_icon.png").similar(0.9))
nn = getLastMatches()
print "nn -> ",list(nn)
while nn.hasNext():
    print "excel --> ",nn.next()
```

The above one is the code.  Here, I am trying to find all MS excel icons on the desktop, and then 
printing it one by one. When I run this, only the output of 3rd line of code was visible in the Message box of sikuli and it wasn't printing the 5th line. 
Output:-

```
nn -> [Match[470,936 53x56 score=0.98 target=center], Match[394,936 53x56 score=0.98 target=center]
```

But, when I replace `list(nn)` by `nn` in the third line

```
print "nn -> ",nn
```

The output I got is:-

```
nn -> org.sikuli.script.Finder@4b0431
excel --> Match[470,936 53x56 score=0.98 target=center]
excel --> Match[394,936 53x56 score=0.98 target=center]
```

I am confused why it is not printing the 5th line when I use line() in the 3rd line.  Could any one help me out??

Comment: There is a bug in above code. "exfind" should be replaced with "nn".

Comment: @MarcinKowalczyk Sorry I meant "nn" not "exfind", I have edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*getLastMatches()* returns object of class Finder which is an Iterator.

Following code:

```
print "nn -> ",list(nn)
```

iterates *nn* while

```
print "nn -> ",nn
```

doesn't iterate.

That's why *nn.hasNext()* returns false after executing *list(nn)* first. To understand it better, run *while* twice like this:

```
print "first while"
while exfind.hasNext():
    print "excel --> ",exfind.next()
print "second while"
while exfind.hasNext():
    print "excel --> ",exfind.next()
```

There will be nothing displayed after "second while".